# Expected an assignment or function and instead saw an expression

Tags: javascript

Below is the piece of code I'm having a problem with. I get the JShint "Expected an assignment or function and instead saw an expression".

```
function checkVal(inputField) {
        ( inputField.val() === '' ) ? inputField.prev('.cd-label').removeClass('float') : inputField.prev('.cd-label').addClass('float');
    }
});
```

Comment: idk if it's related, but he first thing that I notice is the extra `});` at the end?

Answer (score 4):

The warning is telling you that the following line could be a mistake or bug:

```
( inputField.val() === '' ) ? inputField.prev('.cd-label').removeClass('float') : inputField.prev('.cd-label').addClass('float');
```

Its an expression using the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) that returns the value after the `?` if the expression before it is true, or the value after the `:` otherwise. So basically, it's like a shorthand `if` statement that results in an assignment.

To remove the warning, you need to assign it to a variable like this:

```
var yourVariable = ( inputField.val() === '' ) ? inputField.prev('.cd-label').removeClass('float') : inputField.prev('.cd-label').addClass('float');
```

However, for your case you probably don't really want to assign this to anything, so you should just use an `if` statement instead.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using an `if` block here.

```
if( inputField.val() === '' ){
    inputField.prev('.cd-label').removeClass('float');
}
else{
    inputField.prev('.cd-label').addClass('float');
}
```

The ternary operator (`?:`) should only be used in a context where it *returns* a value.  Such as:

```
var x = condition ? 'a' : 'b';
```